# how to install jar file in the wireless toolkit emulator using command prompt in j2me?

Tags: java, java-me, jar, midlet

is their any way so that i can install .jar and .jad file in emulator... through command prompt...

i have written this in the command prompt

```
 C:/WTK2.5.2_01/bin eumlator -XDescriptor: C:/Documents and Settings/saurav/j2mewtk/2.5.2/apps/MyProject/bin
```

but this is not working

error which cmd is showing is this

```
C:/WTK2.5.2_01/bin is not reconnized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: is their any way... if not than say no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WTK's emulator doesn't have any concept of app installation.

What you can do is, you can load it in emulator and run it .

here you go

```
/path/tp/wtk/bin/ eumlator -XDescriptor:/path/to/yourapp/yourapp.jad
```

Comment: please check the question again i have made few changes and added the error i am facing

Comment: can you see `emulator.exe` in your `C:\\WTK\bin`  ?? if not then navigate to proper path and then execute this.

Comment: yes i can see the emulator.exe and on running emulator.exe i am seeing xdescriptor written on the cmd

Comment: all i have to give path to the jad file isn't it

Comment: it worked thanx... i went to that wtk path and entered emulator -xdescriptor:... then the file browser dialog box poped up and then selected the jad file from the path... thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

In the emulator in its screen there is a field in idle view: "Install application"
it brings you to "Enter a website to install from" window.
press tray menu and select 'Storage'  option . Now you can put in the path . For instance: 'c:/temp/ajad.jad' ,(or jar)
Now choose in menu install.