# How to connect NFC in J2ME emulator

Tags: java

how to do the connection for NFC in j2me emulator.
If anyone has already work on this project kindly help me to figure out the problem,
and please shared me if you have any demo code related to this project.
Thanks

Comment: what emulator are you using? you should have some sort of options panel in that emulator, and if the emulator supports NFC, then you can set it.

Comment: hi, i am using DefaultFxPhone1 emulator in netbeans and i don't find any option for NFC, and even i try using the DefaultColor Phone in eclipse and there too i couldn't find any option for NFC.
I am very new to J2ME so please kindly help me if you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

The NFC J2ME implementation is [JSR-257 Contactless Communication API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=257). I suppose you are using [WTK 2.5.2_01](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html).

From that link you can see that there are ~20 modules supported out-of-the-box, but not the JSR-257, so you'll have to load it in the emulator.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741505/how-to-install-jar-file-in-the-wireless-toolkit-emulator-using-command-prompt-in) has a command line solution, but there should be the possibility to load it from the Netbeans GUI.

Comment: Hi linski, All i can found here in JSR-257 Contactless Communication API is about Card emulation and Read/write the Tags mode, but my project is base on peer to peer communication, so my requirement is LLCP mode... kindly inform me if this JSR-257 Contactless Communication API supports LLCP and can we test NFC using two J2ME emulator on same PC using connection center and nfcc simulator? thanks anyway for helping me.

Comment: I'm not sure. Some NFC LLC subset must be implemented but is it enough for your needs, I really can't tell. My suggestion is to contact the http://www.nfc-forum.org/home/ team directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Nokia 6212 NFC emulator. I've developed with it on Windows Vista. Seems to work on Windows 7 too... http://developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/5bcaee40-d2b2-4595-b5b5-4833d6a4cda1/S40_Nokia_6212_NFC_SDK.html